# How to construct polygons from explicit equations?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

Suppose I have an explicit equation that could represent an object shape in OpenGL, how should I sort of "plot" out the shape from the explicit equation?

For example, I have this explicit equation: 
[image]

Both `u` and `v` are members of the real numbers.

I then tried to do this in OpenGL C++:

```
float maxParts = 20;

vector<float> point(3);

glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
for(int i=0; i<=maxParts; i++) {
    float u = ((float)i/maxParts)*2*M_PI;
    for(int j=-maxParts; j<=maxParts; j++) {
        float v = (j/maxParts) * M_PI;
        point[0] = cos(u) * (4.0+3.8*cos(v));
        point[1] = sin(u) * (4.0+3.8*cos(v));
        point[2] = (cos(v) + sin(v) - 1.0) * (1.0 + sin(v)) * log(1.0-M_PI*v/10.0) + 7.5 * sin(v);
        glVertex3f(point[0], point[1], point[2]);
    }
}
glEnd();
```

But it turns out to be just really crappy. The above code somewhat gives a slight impression of the shape but the polygons are not rendered properly. How should I iterate through the explicit equation for the x, y and z coordinates to construct the shape from the equation?

Comment: Well, this is definitely not trivial. First you have to understand how the quad strip primitive works. It first draws a quad from the first 4 vertices you define. It then draws a quad for each new pair of vertices made up of the last 2 vertices of the previous quad and the 2 newly defined vertices. Having this in mind, you'll understand that you can't just go and iterate over the points of your shape however you like, you have to define the quads so that they actually lay on the surface of the shape. I suggest you look up triangle stripification for some insight on this topic.

Comment: You are right about this. The same thing would happen with triangle strip if I looped it as what I did above because the loop is linear and the points are all joined to become a line. But I can't think of other ways to find out a vertices on the surface that can join up to be a triangle or quad. What else could I do?

Comment: If you are working with parametric equations you might also be interested in adjusting step size while plotting (eg. depending on parametrice equations derivative). Otherwise you might get some areas with veeery little polygons(low quality), and others with way too many (low performance if step is lowered to make the previous look better).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're generally going into the right direction. However you missed the crucial step, that you'll have to split down the patch into smaller quads (tesselate it). So you don't just iterate over the sampling points, you iterate over the patches and must generate 4 sampling points for each patch.

Also you need to supply the vertex normals. The vertex normals are given by taking the cross product of the vectors *δ{x,y,z}/δu* and *δ{x,y,z}/δv*

**EDIT due to comment**

Code example for emitting independent quads:

```
const int patches_x, patches_y;
const float patch_size_x, patch_size_y;
int px, py;
for(px = 0; px < patches_x; px++) for(py = 0; py < patches_y; py++) {
    const float U = px * patch_size_x;
    const float V = py * patch_size_y;
    {
        float u, v;
        u = U - patch_size_x/2.0;
        v = V - patch_size_y/2.0;
        emit_quad_vertex(u, v);
    }
    {
        float u, v;
        u = U + patch_size_x/2.0;
        v = V - patch_size_y/2.0;
        emit_quad_vertex(u, v);
    }
    {
        float u, v;
        u = U + patch_size_x/2.0;
        v = V + patch_size_y/2.0;
        emit_quad_vertex(u, v);
    }
    {
        float u, v;
        u = U - patch_size_x/2.0;
        v = V + patch_size_y/2.0;
        emit_quad_vertex(u, v);
    }
}
```

Comment: the code I posted in my question uses a loop and the coordinate points are therefore iterated in a linear sequence. I have thought of iterating it through patches too but is it possible with just the loops? How can I loop the coordinates in the sequence of like top, down, left, right, instead of the one I have now, which iterative from left to right linearly?

Comment: @xEnOn: It's usually easier to loop over the patches, than dynamically adjust loop iterations and step sizes to traverse along the edges. You might want to split this into a two fold process. First generating the vertices (the first loop stays at is is), then creating face index arrays.

Comment: I have been trying for the past few hours but still couldn't figure out an algorithm to loop over the patches instead of the points linearly. Are there any sample code or demo out there on this? Sorry about it as I'm pretty new to OpenGL and C++.